# Is it possible to configure non-global listeners declaratively?

Tags: java, declaration, quartz-scheduler, listener, scheduler

Is it possible to configure (registering with scheduler) non-global job listeners declaratively in properties file (rather than programmatically) similar to [configuring global listeners](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/configuration/ConfigListeners.html)?

Check here for:

1. [Programmatically adding a global job
   listener](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#addGlobalJobListener(org.quartz.JobListener))
2. [Programmatically adding a non-global job listener](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#addJobListener(org.quartz.JobListener))

**EDIT:** Example for configuring a Global JobListener:

```
org.quartz.jobListener.NAME.class = com.foo.MyListenerClass
org.quartz.jobListener.NAME.propName = propValue
org.quartz.jobListener.NAME.prop2Name = prop2Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted this same question in Quartz forum also. Check [here](http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/4188.page)

Answer is '**No**'.

Answer (score 1):

Meantime, I'm also reading that Non-global listeners (and having a job/trigger name its listeners) are considered deprecated and would be completely removed in Quartz v2.0.

Check [here](http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/4016.page) on this for further reading.

But still I'm looking/finding out whether this can be configured/registered declaratively in atleast Quartz v1.8.3, which is the version I'm currently using.